# Waiting until function returns a value before proceeding in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have two functions:

- getPrice(ticker), which makes an API call and returns a stock price
- setStock(e) which should set the state after getPrice returns

As I understood, if I put "await" before a function call as I do in setStock() before getPrice(), the code should not continue executing until getPrice() returns. Clearly, I didn't fully understand it because right now it returns undefined. How do I fix this?

Also, the getPrice(ticker) function accepts a ticker as an argument, so that I can use the function for different stocks. Is this a good way of making API calls?

```
    getPrice = (ticker) => {
      axios.get(`https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/${ticker}/price`)
       .then((res) => {
         const price = res.data;
         return price;
       }).catch((err) => {
           console.log(err);
         });

    }

    setStock = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const ticker = e.target.elements.tickers.value;
      const quantity = e.target.elements.tickers_quant.value;
      const price = await this.getPrice(ticker);
      const stock = {
        ticker,
        price,
        quantity
      }
      this.setState({
        stocks: [...this.state.stocks,stock]
      });
    }
```

Comment: What about `setTimeout` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning a promise in your `getPrice` method, you are just calling it. You are using an arrow function and you have a body block which needs an explicit return. So, use this:

```
getPrice = ticker => {
  return axios
    .get(`https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/${ticker}/price`)
    .then(res => {
      const price = res.data;
      return price;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

or drop the body block and use an implicit return.

```
getPrice = ticker =>
  axios
    .get(`https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/${ticker}/price`)
    .then(res => {
      const price = res.data;
      return price;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not specifically returning anything from your `getPrice` function. That's why it returns `undefined`. That function can be modified like below to make it work.

```
getPrice = async (ticker) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/${ticker}/price`);
    const price = res.data;
    return price;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return null;
  }
}
```